Golang gorm insert a float64 value always with 0
I have a MariaDB table field with data type of "double" with default property
CREATE TABLE
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `available_percentage` DOUBLE,
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


On the other hand, I define a struct in my program that
type A struct {
    ID                    uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    AvailablePercentage   float64
    Date                  string `gorm:"primaryKey;index"`
}

When I try to insert a new record to this table with
&A{
        Date:                  "2024-10-09",
        AvailablePercentage:   float64(99.55),
}

I always get a value of 0 to this field.
I tried with other number, e.g. 100, 99.55000, etc. no different.
Could someone tell what's wrong with my struct or with my MariaDB table field definition?

I'm not an expect in gorm, but to me, it looks like in your A type, you have all fields except AvailablePercentage annotated to have a proper mapping to the DB fields, and AvailablePercentage != available_percentage. So, I would say that gorm just skips that field.

Hi Kostix, to be honest, the A struct not only has these fields, it has a field of TechnicalName which in DB table, the column name is technical_name, they are mapped very well

Have you tried using only float instead of float64? Also, try using one of the types for the type tag available in the doc https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags. Something like:
AvailablePercentage float64 `gorm:"type:double"`

Anyway, I recommend avoiding GORM or any other ORM as much as possible. Try using something like https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel instead.

Hi Silvia, thanks for your response.
I tried with adding "gorm:"type:double"" to the field, still got 0 when testing.
As well as change the field type from float64 to float32

Finally, I got the reason is that I forgot to parse the field of AvailablePercentage in my function...
So funny... So stupid of me...
:)
Thanks all!

Could you specify what exactly have you missed or how you have fixed your issue?

I missed a field in Golang struct
